# What wrong with this while loop? - Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to ask the user for an input number n, and then print all squares less than n. For example, if n = 100, I want it to print 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81.

I did the following:

```
n = float(input("Please enter a positive number: "))

square = 0.0

while square < n:
    square = square + 1
    print(square * square)
```

But then if I execute it, and enter n = 100, this prints all squares up to 1000. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looping from 0 to `n`, and then print the square of that number. 100 * 100 is 10000.

Rename your `square` variable; it is not accurately reflecting what you are counting, it is the *root*, not the square value. In effect, it is just straight-up counter, incrementing by 1 each step. Then test if the *square of the counter* is smaller than `n`:

```
root = 0.0
while root * root < n:
    root = root + 1
    print(root * root)
```

If you must store the square, do actually store the square, not the root:

```
root = square = 0.0
while square < n:
    root = root + 1
    square = root * root
    print(square)
```

Next, move the increment *after* the `print()` if you expected 81 to be the last number printed:

```
root = 0.0
while root * root < n:
    print(root * root)
    root = root + 1
```

This ensures you print the square of the number you just tested, not the *next* root.

Comment: I see, thanks. I tried using the first code you implented, but this also prints 100, instead of exiting at the number 81 (if n = 100). Why is this?

Comment: Because it prints the root as soon as it calculates the new root, if you want it to not print `100` , start at `1.0` , print first and then calculate new root.

Comment: @Kamil: increment the root *after* printing then. You incremented the root right after testing, `9 * 9` is smaller than 100, then you add 1 and print `10 * 10`.

Comment: I think there should be a if statement in here it goes one number beyond the expected result

Comment: @VigneshKalai: no, just move the increment *after* the print.

Answer (score -2):

if you are looking for an easy code you can use this----->>

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(0,n):
   print(i*i)
```

i think it is simple.....

Comment: This prints all squares whose **square roots** are less than `n`.  OP wants to print all squares less than `n`.

Comment: A small modification would work well. `root = int ( math.sqrt( int( input("input an integer and hit enter\n") ) ) )` _ `for i in range(root):` _ `print(i*i)` but what you have there is incorrect.